# Capybara/RSpec 'have_css' matcher not working but has_css does

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

In a Rails 3.2.14 app with Ruby 2, using rspec-rails 2.14.0 and capybara 2.1.0 the following feature spec is causing a failure:

```
require 'spec_helper'

feature 'View the homepage' do
  scenario 'user sees relevant page title' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_css('title', text: "Todo")
  end
end
```

The failure message is:

```
 1) View the homepage user sees relevant page title
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('title', text: "Todo")
 Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
   expected to find css "title" with text "Todo" but there were no matches. Also
   found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
```

**The title element and correct text *are* on the rendered page**

But when I change this line in the feature spec:

```
expect(page).to have_css('title', text: "Todo")
```

to this:

```
page.has_css?('title', text: "Todo")
```

then the test passes. [Edit - but see response below from @JustinKo that this test is not a good test as it will always pass]

**How do I get the `have_css(...)` form to work? Is it a configuration issue?**

Here's the relevant part of my `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails' 
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

And my `spec/spec_helper.rb` is set up like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  # out of the box rspec config code ommitted

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: please go ahead and read this post, especially the capybara part http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: If you do just `page.has_css?('title', text: "Todo")`, the test will always pass. `has_css?` simply returns true or false, which is not sufficient to fail a test. If you output it, you will likely see that it is false. Are you sure the page has a title element with text?

Comment: @JustinKo Thanks for pointing out the newbie error. Yes, the title is showing up with the appropriate text - checked in the browser.

Comment: Are you sure it is the 'title' element not 'H2' or 'H3'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default, Capybara only looks for "visible" elements. The head element (and its title element) are not really considered visible. This results in the title element being ignored in have_css.

You can force Capybara to also consider non-visible elements by the `:visible => false` option.

```
expect(page).to have_css('title', :text => 'Todo', :visible => false)
```

However, it would be easier to use the `have_title` method:

```
expect(page).to have_title('Todo')
```

Comment: Thanks - `have_title` works :). I was following a tutorial that used the `have_css` method, which worked for them (on the video), but perhaps it was because they were using an older version of Caypbara, and maybe `has_css` has been deprecated. I see that `have_title` isn't listed in the [Capybara matchers documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers), nor in the RSpec docs either as far as I can see, which makes life a bit trickier getting one's head around these things as someone new to the task.

Comment: `have_title` is in the rdocs - see http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/RSpecMatchers.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - really helpful. I didn't realise there was a separate matchers section for RSpec - it's not an obvious distinction. Although, looking at the docs, while the `have_` matchers are in there, none have any explanation against them, which still makes it tough!

Comment: `:visible => false` works for finding `script` and `link` tags too :)